# How to attach an image via ActiveStorage directly from web url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am hoping for a very simple way to attach an image from a url

I hoped this would work

```
u = User.first
u.image.attach("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/24/17/d6/2417d6b3f3dc236b0b5b80fb00b3a791.png")
```

I've looked at around 20 SO posts addressing related issues (lots around how to attach an image from the file system) but can't find one attaching from a url

Answer (score 2):

You can use the module open-uri.

```
require 'open-uri'

image = URI.open('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/24/17/d6/2417d6b3f3dc236b0b5b80fb00b3a791.png')
u.image.attach(io: image, filename: 'name.png', content_type: 'image/png')
u.save!
```